# ERROR - TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror

I found the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not sub" in line 24: u[i]=un[i]-c*dt/dx*(un[i]-un[i-1])

Here the complete code:

```
import numpy 
from matplotlib import pyplot
import time, sys
import copy

nx=41
dx=2/( nx-1 )
nt=25
dt=.025
c=1

u=numpy.ones(nx)

u[int(.5/dx):int(1/dx+1)] =2

print(u)

un = numpy.ones(nx)

for n in range(nt):
 un(i)=copy.copy(n)
 for i in range (1,nx):
     u[i]=un[i]-c*dt/dx*(un[i]-un[i-1])
```

Thanks.

Comment: The problem isn't with ```un(i)=copy.copy(n)```? Why do you not simply do ```un[i]=n```?

Comment: You are right. I just changed   un(i)=copy.copy(n)    to     un = u.copy() and it worked. Thanks a lot.